# Product of Uncountably Infinite Number of 1s

Tags: infinite-product

Just like the title says: What is the product of an uncountable number of 1s?  Intuitively the answer is 1, but how does one go about defining such a product in general?

Comment: Take the logarithm, and you get a sum of uncountably many zeroes, which in some settings might be interpreted as an integral. Those do not always sum to $0$.

Comment: Without defining how an uncountably infinite product is calculated, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Classic definition of product cannot be used as product has its left and right factor, and consequently for many factors a row is given which is countable in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **5xum** said in the comments, it depends on how you define the product of an uncountable set of real numbers. Suppose that $\Lambda$ is an uncountable index set, and $a_\lambda\in\Bbb R$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Perhaps the most natural definition of $\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a_\lambda$ is the following.

> Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of all finite subsets of $I$; $\mathscr{F}$ is [directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) by $\subseteq$. For each $F\in\mathscr{F}$ let $a_F=\prod_{\lambda\in F}a_\lambda$; then $\nu=\langle a_F:F\in\mathscr{F}\rangle$ is a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) of real numbers, and we say that $\nu$ converges to $a\in\Bbb R$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $F_\epsilon\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $|a_F-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $F_\epsilon\subseteq F\in\mathscr{F}$. If $\nu$ does converge to some $a\in\Bbb R$, we define $\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a_\lambda=a$; otherwise, the product is undefined. (It’s not hard to see that $\nu$ can converge to at most one real number.)

If we apply this definition to the specific example in your question, in which $a_\lambda=1$ for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$, we find that $a_F=1$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$, so clearly $\nu$ converges to $1$, and the product is therefore $1$ (with this definition of product).

Comment: Curiously, is there an uncountable collection of nonzero real numbers with uncountably many elements not equal to $1$ such that the product of these numbers given by your definition is defined?

Comment: @Batominovski: Yes: if at least one $a_\lambda=0$, the product is $0$: for any $\epsilon>0$ take $F_\epsilon=\{\lambda\}$. But that should be the only exception.

Comment: I realized that a bit after I posted the question, so I edited the question to exclude zeros.  That is, is there such a collection with nonzero elements?  Sorry for the confusion.  Let me add another requirement: the product is also nonzero.  To me, it seems that the only possible products are $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @Batominovski: Sorry; I missed the edit. I originally thought not, but I’ve reconsidered. Suppose that $a_\lambda=\frac12$ for each $\lambda$: then $a_F=2^{-|F|}$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$, so $\nu\to 0$.

Comment: Yep, I added another edit again.  This must be frustrating to you, sorry.  :D

Comment: I am thinking about how to get the product to be $1$ without any $1$ in the collection.

Comment: @Batominovski: Let’s stick to positive reals. If uncountably many terms are less than $1$, the only possible limit is $0$, though $\nu$ may not converge at all. Similarly, if there are uncountably many terms greater than $1$, the only possible limit is $\infty$. Thus, to get limit $1$, all but countably many terms must be $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Proposition: the product of all positive reals (or any uncountable set of real numbers, along with their reciprocals) is 1.  "Proof":  We can pair off each number with its reciprocal, giving an uncountable set of sub-products, all 1; now use your earlier result.  Is this legal (associating and commuting across such a set)? I can't see how to prove this directly with the definition...

Comment: @Jon: It’s false for this definition of the product; in that case the product is undefined.

Comment: @Jon: Your specific method to define a product is similar to reordering conditionally convergent series to get any required sum.

Comment: @z100 Yeah, I thought it sounded fishy. ;)